# Using flexbox to center dynamical objects

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When the game starts, flexbox centering works great (on static objects).
During the game progress both (title and remain divs) change their values/sizes, so that causes to constantly adjusting center positioning by flexbox (all divs in header are moving).

I want each div inside header to stay "fixed" during the game.

**Is that possible just by using flexbox or should i use another approach?
Should I position each element individually?**

You can watch header behaviour on the remote server:
https://stacho163.000webhostapp.com/firstLevel.html

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

#game-window {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vw * 16/9;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -46%);
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="lifes">
      Life1 Life2 Life3
    </div>
    <div id="title">
      Title (changes when you win)
    </div>
    <div id="remain">
      Remaining: (from 100 to 0)
    </div>
  </header>
  <canvas id="game-window"></canvas>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nfzj183t/14/

I am asking, as I don't have much experience in web stuff and i want to use the correct approach to solve this simple problem. 
Thank you in advance for your tips :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach could be to use grid for the main layout and inside every element of grid, use flexbox components.

header would be something like:

```
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 10vh;
}
```

And you will need to make every column a "display: flex;" container. This would be an example with the "lifes":

```
#lifes{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I can show you more complex examples if needed.

Reference: https://gridbyexample.com/examples/

Comment: that's pretty close. If inside div there is only one element it's working well, but inside #lifes div there are 3 objects so the output is distributed like with the use of justify-content: space-between. Lifes should stick next to each other while being centered in #lifes. Any idea how to fix this? I updated this on remote server.

Comment: The problem is in the "margin: auto" of the class fas applied to each icon. Set that margin to 0 or 10px for example. The value "auto" is making the margin fill all of the available space. Nice game btw, It's impressive.

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't spot the margin: auto, works great!